# Replacing multiple substrings in a filename with one (bash or zsh)

Tags: bash, zsh, replace

I have a text file with filenames, where the filenames contain information in various formats (e.g., resolution 4k, 4K, 2160, XxY etc) and I want to rename files to a singular consistent format.

When I only do one pattern, I have been doing as below (extract from script), but is there a way for me to adjust line 1 to include some form of regular expression (OR operator) with multiple substrings, or change line 3 in some fashion.

```
line1: findhighresmarker=".4k."
line2: replaceWith=".2k."
line3: newFileName2K=${file//$findhighresmarker/$replaceWith}
```

Alternative solutions are of course equally welcome and much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like the "fields" of the filenames are delimited with dot/period (`.`) characters.  Is this true?

Comment: often yes (but not always; however, if a solution would necessitate that, I guess that can be arranged")

Comment: It's not a requirement, but since you're asking for a solution that covers more fields in the filename, the more consistent your filenames are with their field delimiters, the easier it will be to craft a technique that covers more fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rename files using regular expressions, then use the perl `rename` utility.  Depending on your OS / distro, this might be called `rename`, `prename`, `perl-rename`, `file-rename` or similar.

It is **not** the same as the `rename` utility in `util-linux`, that is a completely different program with completely different capabilities and incompatible command-line options.

To find out which, if any, you have installed, run one or more of the command names mentioned above with the `-V` option.  If it's perl rename, it will mention either "perl" or "File::Rename".  If it's the `util-linux` version, it will mention that.  It's not uncommon to have both installed on a Linux system, e.g. util-linux version as `rename` or `rename.ul`, and the perl version as `prename` or `file-rename`.

For example, on Debian with both installed:

```
$ rename.ul -V
rename.ul from util-linux 2.38.1

$ rename -V
/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 2.01
```

Anyway, to rename the patterns you suggested, you could use something like this:

```
rename -n 's/resolution 4k|3840x2160|2160/4k/' ./*
```

The `-n` option makes this a dry-run, it will only print what would be renamed without actually renaming anything.  When you're sure it's going to do what you want, remove the `-n` or replace it with `-v` for verbose output.

You can add as many `s///` substitution operations as you like, separated by semi-colon characters, and they will be applied in turn to each filename.  In fact, you can use any valid perl code inside a `rename` script (even variables and subroutines as long as you're careful about variable scope - it's running in `strict` mode). For example, you could write a rename script to examine a file name, setting variables according to the patterns it matches, and then constructing a completely new filename based on the variables that have been set.

If all you use are simple substitution operations, you can think of it as being kind of like `sed` for filenames.

e.g.

```
rename -n 's/resolution 4k|3840x2160|2160[pi]?/4k/;
           s/resolution 2k|2560x1440|1440[pi]?/2k/;
           s/1920x1080|1080[pi]?/HD/;
           s/720x480|480[pi]|4:3/SD/' ./*
```

Comment: Many thanks cas! This definitely does it beautifully. Thanks for making me aware about this command and your elaborate examples and description. Excellent!